# Run junit4 test from cmd

Tags: junit4

I tried to run junit4 test case from command line using:

```
java -cp junit-4.8.1.jar;test\Dijkstra;test\Dijkstra\bin org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Data0PathTest00
```

but I got the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: graph/shortestgraphpath;
```

while the test case is working without any problems in eclipse.

Hint: in eclipse, `shortestgraphpath` was added in Referenced Libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to the jar file containing `shortestgraphpath` to java class path.

```
java -cp junit-4.8.1.jar;test\Dijkstra; test\Dijkstra\bin org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Data0PathTest00
```

The class path is the value that you pass to java with `-cp` so in your question you just supply `junit`and your compiled classes.
Try updating it with the jar file with the missing class.

```
 java -cp junit-4.8.1.jar;<path to jar file>;test\Dijkstra;test\Dijkstra\bin org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Data0PathTest00
```

You might have to add additional jar files as well. I recommend that you take a look at some build tool to help you build and run your java applications for example [Maven](http://maven.apache.org), [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org), [Buildr](http://buildr.apache.org).